# Globally known variable for Web Service Application

Tags: c#, web-services, session-state

I need a globally known variable on a web service application.
Since is web based, a globally declared variable's value remains the same when it is called again.

I also tried to use Session on the web method but it is cleared when the other method is called.

Here is a code sample.

UI portion

```
private void btnOKLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CaprepWS caprepWS = new CaprepWS();
    caprepWS.setDatabase(Program.isProduction);
    string usrInfo = caprepWS.getUserInfo(tbUserName.Text.ToUpper().Trim());
}
```

Web Service portion

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Database switcher", EnableSession = true)]
public void setDatabase(bool isProduction)
{
    Session["isProduction"] = isProduction;
}

[WebMethod(Description = "Get User Info", EnableSession = true)]
public string getUserInfo(string username)
{
    string wsResult = null;
    DataAccess sql = new DataAccess((bool)Session["isProduction"]);

    try
    {
        sql.OpenConn();
        wsResult = sql.Scalar(
              sql.spReader(sqlRoot + "spGetUserInfo.SQL")
            , username);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorWritter(ex.Message);
        wsResult = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        sql.Dispose();
    }

    return wsResult;
}
```

But even if I'm using the same instance on the UI, the session is not known (on the getUserInfo) on the other method and it is null.

The thing is I am avoiding to put this variable on every web method as a parameter on my web service which is why I need it to be globally declared.

Comment: how bout using static variable

Comment: The static variable works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for configuration settings for your application.

I.e. if you are running your service with ASP.Net than config would be [web.config](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301726/Web-config-File-ASP-NET) and custom value look like:

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="IsProduction" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Code to read with [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx):

```
 var isProduction = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsProduction"] == "true";
```